# How to build and publish Flutter Web project using Codemagic CI?

Tags: flutter-web, codemagic

Using Codemagic CI, I'm trying to build a Flutter Web project but I get this error:

```
== Building for Web ==

== /usr/local/bin/flutter packages pub global run webdev build ==
webdev could not run for this project.
You have a dependency on flutter which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
pub finished with exit code 78
```

By reading the error message I thought I have a dependency that is not compatible with Flutter Web, so I deleted every dependency not related to Web. Ones I left are dependencies should work with Flutter Web. The error remains the same. Am I missing something?

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: bonarego_guide_module
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  flutter_beautiful_popup: ^1.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_web_compilers:
  build_runner:

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
  fonts:
    - family: Comfortaa-Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like webdev was a CLI designed to work with Flutter Web when it was a seperate repository (now it's merged into flutter). I've made several modifications and I'm not sure which one was the required but I think setting flutter version as master on build properties of Codemagic solved the issue.